# Scanning APIs with ZAP Docker image - How to provide Bearer Token?

Tags: security, owasp, zap

```
replacer.full_list(0).description=auth1
replacer.full_list(0).enabled=true
replacer.full_list(0).matchtype=REQ_HEADER
replacer.full_list(0).matchstr=apim-Key
replacer.full_list(0).regex=false
replacer.full_list(0).replacement=keyvalue12345
```

Now where should I provide the Bearer Token?

& when provide it like this

replacer.full_list(0).replacement=Bearer --bGciOiJSUzI1NiI

This **space** is giving problem between Bearer and Token.

Note: "" also not working

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add a header then theres an easier way - just st the environmental variables as per https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/authentication/#envvars